# Basic VLAN configuration with Dell PowerConnect 2848

Tags: networking, dell-powerconnect

I'm hoping someone will help me since I've been googling around for some answers but I can't seem to get a straight forward answer.

Disclaimer first... I'm not a network guy, programmer by trade.

So I inherited an environment consisting of a Dell PowerConnect 2848.   All our workstations, servers and VOIP system is hooked up into this one device.  Looking in the admin utility, it seems that it's just one VLAN (the default #1).   Here's what I want to do.   I want to break it up to 3 VLANs, one for voice, another for vmware esxi/storage and one for everything else.   What do I need to do.

What I've done so far: read the dell pdf.   Created the 2 addition vlan membership (101 - vmware, 201 - voice for a total of 3... include default 1).   Now I think I'm supposed to tag and untag which ports are associated to which vlan membership but I'm stuck at that point.   What should be a T and what should be a U and I'm guessing I also need to put in an ethernet cable connecting the T and U correct?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Stop right there... with that class of gear you're just complicating things with little to no benefit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. None of the ports need to be tagged. Tagging would be relevant to a trunk port if your VLAN's span two or more switches or if you're planning on using VST (Virtual Switch Tagging) in whatever VMware product you're using. With only a single switch and no VST, tagging is unneccessary.
2. You need to configure which ports are members of which VLAN's.
3. You need a router to route traffic between the VLAN's. The PowerConnect 2848 is a layer 2 switch and doesn't have any routing ability.
4. Your statement:

> I'm guessing I also need to put in an ethernet cable connecting the T and U correct?

Is incorrect. You shouldn't connect any switch port to any other switch port. You need to connect the correct hosts/devices to the correct switch ports based on their VLAN membership.

Comment: I was thinking that the switch can act as a router also (hence the connect from port to another port).

Comment: Even if the switch were a layer 3 switch and was capable of routing (which it isn't) you wouldn't facilitate that routing by connecting one switch port to another switch port. You would facilitate routing by configuring what is generally referred to as Inter-VLAN routing.

Comment: Okay.. I have a Cisco RV042 VPN / Router.   I'll see if I can use that as my router and then link them with ports that correspond to the 3 VLANs.